# why google map does not show duplicate markers?

Tags: google-maps

why google map does not show duplicate markers?

My data has duplicate addresses - how to make them all appear e.g.  1-3 markers per city?

```
var map =
        new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

     var options = {};
        options['dataMode'] = 'markers';
        options['showTip'] = 'true';


    map.draw(geoView, options);
```

Comment: duplicate addresses? u mean same latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markers overlap so you can only see one. You can tell by a darker shadow. If you want to be able to click all three markers you'll have to do some testing when adding the markers. You can either stagger them a little bit or make one infowindow that incorporates all the markers at that lat/lng